# Data structure and Algorithm issue while using .NET

Tags: c#

In my controller, I have a post method that takes the information from a form, and writes it to the database.  Before I SaveChanges to the database I would like to foreach through the parameter object that is being passed into the method.  The object is called item and is Item type.

When I try to foreach through the object item I receive an error,

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Item' because 'Item' does not contain a public instance defenition for 'GetEnumerator'

I have more experience in the Mean stack so I am not used to receiving type errors for my algorithms.  I came up with a solution using a bunch of if statements but I would rather have cleaner code using a foreach statement.

This is an example of two of my if statements.

```
if (item.CsCost == null)
{
    item.CsCost = 555555555;
}

if (item.Department == null)
{
    item.Department = "Null";
}
```

In my immediate window if I type ?item.  This is the object information that is displayed.  It is a key value pair Dictionary object.  In relation to the database, the keys are the column names, and the value is all the information in the row.

```
? item
{App.Models.Item}
    Approved: null
    Brand: "Disco"
    CsCost: null
    CsPack: 40
    DateApproved: null
    DateRequested: {8/3/2018 11:53:45 AM}
    DateReviewed: null
    Department: null
    Deposit: 0.00
    DepositUpc: null
    Description: "BANANAS"
    FoodStampable: true
    GM: null
    ID: null
    ItemCode: null
    ItemType: "Disco"
    LineExtension: null
    Margin: null
    Merchandiser: null
    NPrice: 0.0
    Notes: null
    PkQty: 1.00
    PluRequest: false
    Qty: 1
    RequestType: "Disco"
    RequestedBy: "jschroeder"
    Reviewed: null
    ScaleTare: 0.00
    ScaleUoM: "LB"
    Section: "50300001"
    Selected: false
    Size: 1.00
    SizeAlpha: "1lb"
    Store: null
    StoreFix: null
    TOB: null
    UOM: "LB"
    UPC: "4011"
    UnCost: null
    UnitSize: 1.0000
    Vendor: "701     "
    Wicable: null
```

This is kind of a two part question regarding type and type errors.
Once I can start foreaching through the object, I would like to find every value which is null.  This I know how to do.  Here is what I don't know how to do.

Once I find the null value of the key value pair, I need to alter the value to 5555555 if the column type is int or decimal, and "Null" if the column type is string.

Here is the sudo code for what I would like to do.

```
function(item){
   foreach(x in item){
      find the value that is null
      if this value is a string then replace with "Null"
      if this value is int then replace with 5555555
 }
}
```

So for example, after this algorithm is complete, the Notes field, item.notes will be {..., Notes: "Null", ...}

Comment: You say that `item` is a `Dictionary`, but what you posted says that `item` is an instance of  `App.Models.Item`. Are you attempting to `foreach` every property of `item`?

Comment: Hey Camilo.  Sorry my terminology is sometimes off.  I think you are right, it is an instance of App.Models.Item so Yes I would like to foreach every property of item.

Comment: You can get started using that duplicate. Then, you can get the value of each property. check its type (`prop.Type == typeof(string)` for example) and assign your default value

Comment: That looks right.  I will try that.  Thank you!

Comment: if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        prop.GetValue(item) = "Null";
                    }  isnt possible though

Comment: You use `prop.GetValue(item)` for getting the value and `prop.SetValue(item, "Null")` or something like that for setting the value